# modify function input through for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, indexing

I have a series of buttons with some names on them; when a button is clicked the name on it is added in a list. This last operation is done by a function which takes as input the id of the button. When I write all that stuff explicitly all works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        inventory=[]

        function addinv(variable) {
            item=document.getElementById(variable).innerHTML
            if (item!='Ok') {
                if (inventory.length<2){
                    inventory.push(item)
                    document.getElementById(variable).innerHTML='Ok'
                }
            }

        }

        function location0() {
            document.getElementById("1").innerHTML="Spada"
            document.getElementById("1").setAttribute('onclick','addinv(1)')
            document.getElementById("2").innerHTML="Corda"
            document.getElementById("2").setAttribute('onclick','addinv(2)')
            document.getElementById("3").innerHTML="Acciarino"
            document.getElementById("3").setAttribute('onclick','addinv(3)')
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="1" onclick=""></button>
    <button type="button" id="2" onclick=""></button>
    <button type="button" id="3" onclick=""></button>
    <script>location0()</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I would like to use a for loop in order to set the names on the buttons and calling the addinv function. For that I changed the function location0 as follows:

```
function location0() {
    equip=["Spada", "Corda", "Acciarino"]
        for (i=1; i<4; i++) {
            document.getElementById(i).innerHTML=equip[i-1]
            document.getElementById(i).setAttribute('onclick','addinv(i)')
        }
    }
```

Now buttons still have the right name on them, but the addinv function does not work properly: it seems to me that all buttons calls addinv(4)

Comment: use `\`addinv(${i})\`` (equivilent to `'addinv(' + i + ')'`)

Comment: *it seems to me that all buttons calls `addinv(4)`* - it does. `i` is a global variable in your code, and ends up being 4 at the end of the loop, and then `addinv(i)` uses that value. If you wrote `for(var i=1;i<4;i++)` (or even `for(let i=1;i<4;i++)`, the global `i` would be `undefined`, assuming there's no such variable elsewhere.

Comment: `addinv(${i})` It does not seems to work; but 'addinv(' + i + ')' it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace the for-loop as below:

```
for (let i=1; i<4; i++) {
   document.getElementById(i).innerHTML=equip[i-1]
   document.getElementById(i).addEventListener("click",()=>{addinv(i)});
}
```

I attached a [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/6bo5dgkv/) for your reference.

Comment: Here you are assigning the *result* of an `addinv(i)` call as event handler.

Comment: with the modification it works

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the id to `addinv()`, I'd suggest passing a ref to the item. So I slightly modified `location0()` and the call to `addinv()`.

```
function location0() {
    const equip=["Spada", "Corda", "Acciarino"]
    
        for (let i=0; i<equip.length; i++) {
          let item = document.getElementById(i+1)
          item.innerHTML = equip[i];
          item.setAttribute('onclick', 'addinv(this)')
        }
    }
```

Then change `addinv()` to this. This should work.

```
function addinv(item) {
    let text = item.innerHTML;
    if (text != 'Ok') {
        if (inventory.length < 3) {
            inventory.push(text)
            item.innerHTML = 'Ok'
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        inventory=[]

        function addinv(variable) {
            item=document.getElementById(variable).innerHTML
            if (item!='Ok') {
                if (inventory.length<3){
                    inventory.push(item)
                    document.getElementById(variable).innerHTML='Ok'
                }
            }

        }

        function location0() {
            document.getElementById("1").innerHTML="Spada"
            document.getElementById("1").setAttribute('onclick','addinv(1)')
            document.getElementById("2").innerHTML="Corda"
            document.getElementById("2").setAttribute('onclick','addinv(2)')
            document.getElementById("3").innerHTML="Acciarino"
            document.getElementById("3").setAttribute('onclick','addinv(3)')
            
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="1" onclick=""></button>
    <button type="button" id="2" onclick=""></button>
    <button type="button" id="3" onclick=""></button>
    <script>location0()
    
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).